# Best format to plot vibration data?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

I am about to present my work on vibrations to a NVH specialist at work and he is supposed to help me.

I have calculated PSD's, now my question (subjective, I know) is how should I plot the data? I've been plotting $PSD \big[\frac{g^2}{Hz}\big]$ against frequency $\big[Hz\big]$, both in linear axes. I've been told the frequency axis should be in logarithmic scale, which makes sense, what about the PSD axis?

Comment: Surely the idea of using a log axis or log-log axis was to get a straight line plot - do you get one or what you get is sufficient. If you can explain your results then the chart you have is sufficient for the purpose.

Comment: One can "prefer" Log PSD-Log f or Log PSD-f for PSD-f plotting, it is preference because this selection may change according to plotted data. Main purpose is to visualize the results in linear. I think the use of "Best Plot" is wrong but there might be a common one. My suggestion is to try both and choose the one suits your plot.

Comment: @SolarMike Good point!

Comment: @F.Bek You're right, I should've asked if there was a standard instead of "what is best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, a PSD for vibration will have a log scale for both axes.

Comment: Thanks! I spoke to a NVH specialist and this is also what he said. For reference if anyone in the future sees this thread, I used dB on y axis and log on x axis which is apparently not common.  As @DLS3141 suggested, log-log is the proper format.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the application. Floor vibration data is typically plotted in 1/3rd octave bands and can have logarithmic y axes or not; sometimes it is also plotted in true-partite format. Other applications use any combination of linear and/or logarithmic axes depending on what is convenient.